# How to compare two dates (not time) in django-python project?

Tags: python, django, date, django-models, django-views

Here It is my function to print the previous(oldTickets) and upcoming(newTickets) bookings.
**journeyDate** is database attribute(column name) which is of type **date** and **ticketDetail** is model name. 
Here It is showing error in comparing date attributes.

```
def booking(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_name = request.user.username
        today = date.today()
        oldTickets = ticketDetail.objects.all()
        oldTickets = ticketDetail.objects.filter(userName=user_name).filter(ticketDetail.journeyDate<today)
        newTickets = ticketDetail.objects.all()
        newTickets = ticketDetail.objects.filter(userName=user_name).filter(ticketDetail.journeyDate>today)
        context = {'oldticket':oldTickets, 'newticket':newticket}
        return render(request, 'bookticket/myBookings.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

Can anyone guide me, how to solve this error?
Thank You :)

Comment: can you please put the error message that you're seeing?

Comment: "*Here It is showing error in comparing date attributes.*" - Which error?

Comment: Together with the relevant models.

Comment: @RafaAcioly @PedroLobito here it;s error message : `'<' not supported between instances of 'DeferredAttribute' and 'datetime.date'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the [**`__lt`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt) and [**`__gt`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) to specify filters with *less than* and *greater than*:

```
def booking(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_name = request.user.username
        today = date.today()
        oldTickets = ticketDetail.objects.filter(
            userName=user_name,
            journeyDate__lt=today
        )
        newTickets = ticketDetail.objects.filter(
            userName=user_name,
            journeyDate__gt=today
        )
        context = {'oldticket':oldTickets, 'newticket':newticket}
        return render(request, 'bookticket/myBookings.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```